# sudo: effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root?

Tags: debian, permissions, sudo

I accidentally changed the ownership on my debian web server in /usr/bin and the permissions are no longer root root but instead USER root. How do I get this back everything I am finding says to restart it but I don't know how to do that through the Google Compute Engine. How do I fix this so I can use sudo?

Answer (score 0):

Check affected files: `ls -lahR /usr/bin/ | grep -v " root   root"`

Fix it `pkexec chown -R "root:root" /usr/bin/`.

> **pkexec** - Execute a command as another user.

(from the [`pkexec` manpage](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/pkexec/))